# How to automatically add a signature?

Tags: pantheon-mail, release-odin

How can I automatically add a signature when composing an email?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'm stumped on this one as well. Is the feature not available in 6.1?

EDIT: It's a forthcoming feature request.  https://github.com/elementary/mail/issues/616